# SQL restricting by foreign key.

Tags: sql

I have a royalties frame and a batches frame. Batches consist of a bunch of royalties batched together.

Basically when in the batch frame, it updates the unallocated royalties after an allocation has been done. However, it tries to match by ROYALTY_ID, which takes forever because there are millions of them. I want to restrict the function by BATCH_ID so it'll massively reduce the search time, but I'm not quite sure how.

Thanks
Dan

---

Current query:

```
UPDATE ROYALTIES 
SET ALLOCATION_STATUS_ID = pRoyaltyStatusId 
WHERE ROYALTIES.RIGHT_TYPE_ID = pRightTypeId 
AND ROYALTIES.WORK_ID = pWorkId 
AND ROYALTIES.TERRITORY_ID = pTerritoryId 
AND ROYALTIES.ROYALTY_PERIOD_END_DATE = UTILS.FIX_DATE(pEndDate);
```

Comment: can you post the sql you are currently using?

Comment: UPDATE ROYALTIES
      SET    ALLOCATION_STATUS_ID              = pRoyaltyStatusId
      WHERE  ROYALTIES.RIGHT_TYPE_ID           = pRightTypeId
      AND    ROYALTIES.WORK_ID                 = pWorkId
      AND    ROYALTIES.TERRITORY_ID            = pTerritoryId
      AND    ROYALTIES.ROYALTY_PERIOD_END_DATE = UTILS.FIX_DATE(pEndDate);

Comment: cheers, can you post the table design as well, should be able to suggest something then

Comment: @Dan Trunley: It would be better if you edited your question to add the script, especially because you can format it nicely in the question post. Same applies to the table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, foreign key constraint does not connect with performance issue. You should look at the INDEX technique. The index for the field BATCH_ID (details table) will improve select query performance.